# Dropdown hiding behind the header

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styling

I'm creating a header and I have multiple items in the header like contact, products etc.

So, I'm creating Products with a dropdown, and if I hover then dropdown should appear.

But due to some issue in my styling it goes behind the header.

Here is codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-worker-btgscc?file=/src/Components/Header.jsx

I'm thinking that this issue is mostly caused by z-index but I tried playing around with it, didn't work.

Comment: Please include a minimal example of the problem in the question itself, an external link is fine as an additional resource, but the code should be visible, as text, in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from your `nav` it will work